# Reading filesystem type at boot into BASH variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, init-script

I have a /etc/rc.d/S11 link to a /etc/init.d file that is trying to set a bash variable of the file system type of a given blkid entry.

```
root@OpenWrt:/# blkid /dev/mmcblk1p3
/dev/mmcblk1p3: UUID="77111d8a-feb7-470c-a489-ffa0e5415c4c" TYPE="f2fs"
root@OpenWrt:/#
```

I attempted to tack a `awk` onto the command

```
root@OpenWrt:/# blkid /dev/mmcblk1p3 | awk '{print $3}'
TYPE="f2fs"
root@OpenWrt:/#
```

Ideally, I just need the `f2fs` without the rest.  Using `awk -F = '{print $3}'` returns

```
root@OpenWrt:/# blkid /dev/mmcblk1p3 | awk -F = '{print $3}' 
"f2fs"
root@OpenWrt:/#
```

In the script, I'm trying to set it as a bash variable so I can use it later in the script.

```
CUR_FS=$(blkid /dev/mmcblk1p3 | awk '{print $3}');
```

However, in the debug message I'm sending to the kernel log, it's blank.

```
echo "[DEBUG] Shield is in ${SHIELD_MODE} Mode - Using /dev/${MNT_POINT} as ${CUR_FS}" > /dev/kmsg
```

Returns

```
[   34.836024] [DEBUG] Shield is in Gateway Mode - Using /dev/mmcblk1p3 as
```

It's blank.

Before someone points out that OpenWrt does not have `bash` (uses ash by default), I am doing a custom build and baked `bash` in.

Can someone point me in the direction getting the end result of just `f2fs` without the double-quotes?

Writing `blkid` output to a file gives empty files.

```
blkid /dev/mmcblk1p3 2>&1 > /tmp/output
lsblk --noheadings -o FSTYPE /dev/mmcblk1p3 2>&1 > /tmp/output2
```

Edit Note: lsblk and blkid are separate on my system, so i tried it both ways.  Still comes up blank.  Could it be that I'm calling it too early?  I've also attempted to put the full hard path to the commands, just in case `$PATH` wasn't set yet - Still blank.

Edit 2: It was suggested that the init script was being called too early.  I set the script to `S99` for testing so that it's called almost last and it the filesystem call is still blank.

S99extroot is the script in question.  Originally, I had it at `S11`.

```
K10gpio_switch   K99umount        S19dropbear      S94gpio_switch                                                          
K10snort         S00sysfixtime    S19firewall      S95done                                                                 
K50dropbear      S10boot          S20network       S96led                                                                  
K85odhcpd        S10system        S35odhcpd        S98sysntpd                                                              
K89log           S11sysctl        S50cron          S99extroot                                                              
K90network       S12log           S50uhttpd        S99urandom_seed                                                         
K90sysfixtime    S12rpcd          S80ucitrack                                                                              
K98boot          S19dnsmasq       S90snort                                                                                 
root@OpenWrt:/#
```

Comment: I didn't notice anything that needs `bash` in your commands. The most likely reason for your empty variable is that `blkid` doesn't output anything for some reason. Write the output and stderr of `blkid` to a file to see what it produces at that stage in the boot sequence.

Comment: Try to use `CUR_FS=$(blkid /dev/mmcblk1p3)` only in your script to see what the output is.

Comment: Since `man blkid` appears to be directing users at `lsblk`, consider this alternative to reduce parsing: `lsblk --noheadings -o FSTYPE /dev/mmcblk1p3`

Comment: @JeffSchaller lsblk is different from blkid command-wise on my system, but I'd rather use your syntax if I can since it returns un-double quoted `f2fs`.  Still returns as blank in the script though

Comment: @Thomas Still shows as blank in the `> /dev/kmsg` and `2>$1 > /tmp/output`

Comment: @RalfFriedl File is empty with `2>$1` file redirect

Comment: I suspected that, there are few other reasons why the result would be empty. Are you sure the device and device file are already available at that time?

Comment: @RalfFriedl The script is called at S11 in init.d.  It's after system and sysctl (sp?  Not at the box right now) but before the firewall init and network and whatnot

Comment: It seems this SD card is mounted even later, then?

Comment: Try to put just `ls -l /dev >/var/tmp/debug.log` in your script to find out if the device file is actually there when your script runs. This doesn't solve it, but it helps to know in what direction to search for a solution.

Comment: @JeffSchaller /dev/mmcblk1 is the internal Flash.  The original OEM image for the device held the extroot `rootfs_data` in those partitions, so I'm not sure when it's called, but I'm going to guess it has to be before the device is full brought up

Comment: @Hkoof Changed the script and you were right, no `/dev/mmcblk1`.  I then moved it to `/etc/rc.local` and STILL not there..  Now I'm confused mas to what is actually going on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delay `init` until the blk device was available.  Put in a `while true` loop to keep checking for it so I could `mknod` it.